# AngularJS application like adobePDF Reader

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have task like I have image sin left pane and right pane. So I need to display like when I am click on left image it'll show exact equal image on right side, like Adobe PDF reader. Actually while working with "div" tags we can place everything easily but I am using folder access like.

```
<html> 
  <body ng-app="">
    <div class="leftPaneImages" ng-controller="ThumbNail as TN" id="rp2">
      <div ng-repeat="tname in TN.imgThumbNames track by $index"   ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()">
        <img ng-src="{{TN.imgDir+tname}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightPaneImages"  ng-controller="PageImage as PI" id="rp1">
      <div ng-repeat="name in PI.imgNames track by $index">
        <img id="myImgId" ng-src="{{PI.imgDir+name}}" ng-mousedown="onMouseDown($event)" />
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

so how can I navigate.could any one please let me know exact solution as earlier..